# perl regular expressions with date

Tags: perl

Trying to validate the date of the format (YYYY_MM_DD).  With the test variable set as 2012_4_123  it's printing "valid format" after script is run.  It should give  an "invalid error" message because in the regular expression  the day part is checked  to be atleast 1 digit and not more than 2 digits.  Not  sure how it's printing "valid format" as the output message.

```
my $test="2012_4_123";
if ($test !~ m/^(\d{4})_(\d{1,2})_(\d{1,2})/)
{
  print "invalid format\n";
}
else
{
 print  "valid format\n";
}
```

Comment: You can omit the parentheses in your regex, unless you're using the captures later on in your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
-if ($test !~ m/^(\d{4})_(\d{1,2})_(\d{1,2})/)
+if ($test !~ m/^(\d{4})_(\d{1,2})_(\d{1,2})$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a `$` at the end. it's matching the string `"2012_4_12"` because you didn't tell it to match the end of the string too. Your regex should be this.

```
$test !~ m/^(\d{4})_(\d{1,2})_(\d{1,2})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding $ solves the initial problem of allowing for more than two digits for the day, but introduces a more subtle bug: dates will now validate despite having a newline at the end. This may not matter depending on your application, but it can be avoided by using the regex in the following example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tests = (
    '2012_4_123',
    '2012_11_22',
    "2012_11_22\n",
);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@tests;

foreach my $test (@tests) {
    if ( $test !~ m/\A(\d{4})_(\d{1,2})_(\d{1,2})\z/smx )
    {
        print "invalid format\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "valid format\n";
    }
}
```

Note: `/smx` is recommended by *Perl Best Practices* and I write my regexes with it unless there's a specific need not to have it, but it may trip you up if you're not used to it.

`/s` and `/m` will allow you to process multiline strings more easily; `/s` because `.` will then match newlines and `/m` to allow you to use `^` and `$` to match the start and end of a line respectively, and `\A` and `\z` will then match the start and end of the entire string.

`/x` is simply to allow whitespace and comments within a regex, though you'll need to escape whitespace if you're actually trying to match it.

In this case, it's using `\z` instead of `$` that makes the difference irrespective of the use of `/smx`.

Also, it mightn't be a bad idea to look at a module to perform date validation rather than just date format validation (again, depending on what you're using this for). See this [discussion on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564594).

Comment: Maybe you should explain what these switches do.

Comment: Yes, not a bad idea, now added.